# Facebook object graph https request from ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, object-graph

How would you do a request to Facebook object graph to get the user's friends?

If you type in the url it works in the browser (replaced by valid user_id and access token):
"https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?access_token=2227470867|2.AQDi3TbqnqrsPa0_.360"

When I try it from ruby code using Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('url')) I get URI::InvalidURIError error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access token has some characters that are invalid for a URL. You have to `CGI.escape` them.

```
require 'cgi'

access_token = '2227470867|2.AQDi3TbqnqrsPa0_.360'
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?access_token=#{CGI.escape(access_token)}"
uri = URI.parse(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path + "?" + uri.query)
response = http.request(request)
data = response.body
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I can add as well, that since it is ssl request, I had to change the code a little bit. 
    `token = access_token['credentials']['token']
    uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/#{id}/friends?access_token=#{CGI.escape(token)}")
    #response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path + "?" + uri.query)
    response = http.request(request)     
    data = response.body`

Comment: @EdijsPetersons, I also updated my answer to include your ssl changes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to do with OAuth? I'd suggest you to use a library like [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) instead of unrolling custom adhoc solutions.

Comment: I tried, but I got error when initializing `@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token['credentials']['token'])`. access_token is coming after callback is made from facebook using omniauth devise environment variable `env["omniauth.auth"]`. I saw that from 1st October there were some object graph changes. Do you have any working example?